# Bangla font in pdf not show correctly in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have used *iReport 5.6.0* for building report.I used *SolaimanLipi* font in my static field. iReport internal view no problem but after save as pdf(Open in pdf reader or any browser) bangla font not show correctly.
jrxml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="challanReport" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="770" leftMargin="54" rightMargin="18" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9126e000-dc70-4a76-9013-4a4fa290f0df">
<pageHeader>
    <band height="273" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="13" y="10" width="403" height="20" uuid="1d2c7070-63f4-4a43-b3a2-63dc4c27c6f2"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SolaimanLipi" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[বাংলাদেশ ব্যাংক/সোনালী ব্যাংকের ....ঢাকা....জেলার....মহাখালী....শাখায় টাকা জমা দেওয়ার চালান ।]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="429" y="10" width="69" height="20" uuid="21401d70-386e-4f01-bf34-586d58991b62"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font fontName="SolaimanLipi" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[১ম(মূল)কপি]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="13" y="50" width="512" height="60" uuid="ee6769a0-b25e-4f60-b783-58b535f955d7"/>
            <box leftPadding="4">
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="SolaimanLipi" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[বিভাগের নাম এবং চালানের পৃষ্ঠাংকনকারী  কর্মকর্তার নাম, পদবী ও দপ্তর l *]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="13" y="30" width="512" height="20" uuid="1e86fa4b-88a3-4e05-b37a-3a4dbd0b2963"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font fontName="SolaimanLipi" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[জমা প্রদানকারী কর্তৃক পূরণ করিতে হইবে |]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
```

iReport internal view:
[image]

iReport outside view:
  [image]
How can solve this?

Comment: Are you using font-extensions?

Comment: @AlexK no. I used Identity-H (Unicode with horizontal writing) and pdf embeded true

Comment: @Rafiq, did you find any solution? I am facing same issue..

Answer (score -1):

### Any Kind of Unicode font correctly showing process in pdf using jasper report

**Step-1**

- Download your desire Unicode font xxx.ttf extension
- Install this font in jasper studio [font Installation instruction](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension)
- Now use this custom font in your report

**Step-2**

- Export your custom font jar from Jaspersoft-studio
- Add this font jar in java build path or install this font in maven repository

If you manually add font in your project build path then ignore font installation process.

**Font installation command**

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/your-jar-file-directory/fontName.jar -DgroupId=bangla -DartifactId=bangla -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

After install font jar you need to add dependency in your pom file

**Sample Dependency example**

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>bangla</groupId>
            <artifactId>bangla</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```